# Difference between emulators

Tags: android, windows, appium, android-virtual-device

I've created a virtual device `Nexus_5X_API_27_x86`. Running through Android Studio it runs fine.

I added `ANDROID_HOME` to point towards `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`, since Appium wants this defined. And `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;` to PATH as according to https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html it uses the emulator executable in there (at least on Mac OS).

But if I run that emulator it panics with:

```
PS D:\AppiumTest> emulator -avd Nexus_5x_API_27_x86
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.
```

There's also no other emulator executables in the tools folder. However if I run it with the emulator in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator` it runs as it should.

```
PS D:\AppiumTest> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator -avd Nexus_5x_API_27_x86
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Saving state on exit with session uptime 2068 ms
```

In the `Sdk\emulator` folder there's also a whole slew of different emulator executables (64, arm, ect.).

So the question is, whats the use of `Sdk\tools\emulator.exe`? Or is my install broken somehow?

Comment: I encountered the same thing quite some time ago, and just settled on the one that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen same things in current version of Android SDK Tools. I think emulator.exe under the "tools" folder is for previous versions of Android SDK Tools, see following link https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator.

If you want to use it now only with installed Android SDK tools you have to download it with sdkmanager.

Answer (score 0):

To properly answer this question, here is the new [documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools#tools-sdk)

> Note: The Android SDK Command-Line Tools package, located in
> **cmdline-tools**, replaces the SDK Tools package, located in **tools**. With
> the new package, you can select the version of the command line tools
> you want to install, and you can install multiple versions at a time.
> With the old package, you can only install the latest version of the
> tools. Thus, the new package lets you depend on specific versions of
> the command-line tools without having your code break when new
> versions are released. For information about the deprecated SDK Tools
> package, see the SDK Tools release notes.

The old SDK tools setup usually breaks the project since it does not support multiple version where you can rollback when the latest version is broken after updating thus this update was made. The emulator in `SDK/tools` is no longer needed with the new Android Studio version.